# WhatsApp's chat history restore failed, trying to restore from local backup also failed

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, restore

On the 14th Aug morning, when I opened WhatsApp, it was saying to restore chat history:

> [image]
>
> #### Restore chat history
>
> Something went wrong with your chat history. Don't worry, you can restore your chat history from backup. If you don't restore now, you won't be able to restore later.
>
> <kbd>SKIP RESTORE</kbd> <kbd>RESTORE</kbd>

I clicked restore but after that, my WhatsApp was all new, only group names were there. Unfortunately, my Google backup was not on, so I checked for local backup files and copied them onto my laptop.

After reinstalling WhatsApp, I am unable to recover my data from these local files. After copying files to the exact folder, it gets detected, but now when it's restored up to 99 percent, it says sorry in the end and I get the WhatsApp all new with just group names.

How to recover from these files? Is any file missing?